# Git bash se cuelga cuando ejecuto "git branch"

Tags: git, bash, gitlab, git-bash

cuando ejecuto el comando "git branch" en el cli de git bash, la consola me muestra las ramas, pero no vuelve al prompt, y queda en suspenso. Adjunto Imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando cierro la consola, arroja el siguiente mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probe reinstalando la aplicación. el resto de los comandos que probe funciona sin problema: push, pull, status, -v, add .

Muchas gracias al que me pueda guiar o encaminar.

Comment: Git va mostrando parte del contenido a veces. Como con `git log`, y `git diff`.  No sé si este sea tu caso, pero intenta presionar la **q** cuando ves que *se traba*.

Comment: Gracias, pero no era eso. sigue sucediendo

Comment: Pensaría que tienes algo configurado en el Shell (se puede ver qué te sale el nombre de la rama en el prompt del Shell: `(dev)`. Probablemente eso esté ejecutando comandos que están tomando demasiado tiempo (por razones que.no tienen relación con git.... Por ejemplo, un FS con mucha latencia?).